# Decorator pattern in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, oop, decorator

Is there anyway to achieve the "Decorator-pattern" such as below in Excel VBA ?

```
Sub runner(subroutine)
MsgBox ("Decoration Before")
Call subroutine
MsgBox ("Decoration After")
End Sub

Sub toBeDecorated()
MsgBox ("to be decorated")
End Sub

Sub fire()
Call runner(toBeDecorated)
End Sub
```

When I try to run the sub "fire", The compiler throws "Compile error: Expected Function or variable"

Comment: Use `application.run` and pass the name of the routine as text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no function/subroutine pointers in VBA, so you can't pass a function or subroutine as parameter. As a consequence, `Call subroutine` will never be valid: The compiler looks for a routine named `subroutine`. This happens at compile time, not at execution time and will create the Compiler error.

A workaround could be using `Application.Run`: The `Run`-method expects the name of a routine as String, so it will evaluate `subroutine` at runtime:

```
Sub runner(subroutine As String)
    MsgBox "Decoration Before"
    Application.Run subroutine
    MsgBox "Decoration After"
End Sub

Sub toBeDecorated()
    MsgBox "to be decorated"
End Sub

Sub fire()
    Call runner("toBeDecorated")
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, Works well.
NOTE : to pass arguments to "subroutine" in Application.Run Use Application.Run subroutine, arg1, arg2, arg3 ...